# Asking questions whose answers are clearly known to the OP

Tags: discussion, policy

What is the Math.SE take on questions like [Perfect set without rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/perfect-set-without-rationals), whose answer, judging from the comment, is known to the OP?

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/241/seeded-questions-set-to-cw

Note that it's explicitly-allowed practice on SO (per the FAQ) to answer your own question (pretty sure you don't get +15 rep for selecting it as the answer, though).

Comment: The asker knowing the answer is not the problem I have with this question. I downvoted it because it looks like the asker copied it from a homework assignment or test without putting any thought into it.

Comment: See also these meta questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/251/what-is-a-seeded-question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/241/seeded-questions-set-to-cw http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-people-make-it-obvious-when-they-are-seeding

Answer (score 10):

I think maybe this question is a "seed" question. See OP's profile:

> I am a Mathoverflow user who wants to enable this site to have high quality, as opposed to being too sloppy a site. So I am seeding the site with good quality questions that are suitable for all college students; but won't be accepted in MathOverflow. I also want this site to be a home to sensible questions that are brutally closed by the question-closers in MathOverflow.

Comment: It seems likely that it is a seed question, yes.  Two points: 1) As the site moves further into public beta, I hope "the need for seed" will decrease to zero in finite time.  2) A question that looks like a homework question may not be such a great question to seed the site with, as the present instance seems to show.