# Ambit of Acceptable Questions

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions whose answers are known to the OP](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/questions-whose-answers-are-known-to-the-op)

Is it acceptable for a poster to post questions to which (s)he knows the answer, with the idea of sharing interesting problems with others?

Comment: Related questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-math-puzzle-on-topic-or-off-topic, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/questions-whose-answers-are-known-to-the-op, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/313/asking-questions-whose-answers-are-clearly-known-to-the-op

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that.